# How can I reset my Ability Points?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm also curious about being able to reset my points, should I wish to change my ability configuration later.

So far (10h-ish) I've only seen one way, which is a potion sold by Kiera Metz for 1000g. However she's no longer available as a store, due to a story choice, so I'm not sure where else I could buy this potion.

Where might I buy this potion, and is it the only way to reset your ability points?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a merchant in Novigrad that sells the Potion of Clearance as well, he's at the location shown in this screenshot, right next to the barber:

[image]

This potion is the only way to reset your skills as far as I know.

Comment: What's the cost, is it still 1000g?

Comment: @DavidYell Yes, still 1000g

Comment: Could you buy as many as you'd like or is there a limit?

Comment: @MasterMastic I've read that they restock, and I've also encountered merchants later that have 5 of those potions.

Comment: Keira Metz, who you'll meet relatively early in the story, also sells at least one of these potions.